# How do I have a floating delete row button for a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to get the finishing touches on a `DataGrid` that I'm building and I'm having some trouble getting the result that I'm looking for.  I have a `DataGrid` that contains my rows and I need to be able to let the users delete the selected column out of the grid.  Initially, I did this by having a button that was external from the grid.  An officemate suggested I put the button inside the grid and so I did.  The button only shows up for the selected row.  Here's the XAML for that:

```
<DataGrid MaxHeight="105" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Item}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Part Number" Binding="{Binding PartNumber}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Date Code" Binding="{Binding DateCode}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Lot Code" Binding="{Binding LotCode}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource NoBorderCellStyle}" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Button Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteItem,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid},Mode=FindAncestor}}" Padding="5,0">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This works well enough, but I don't like the last column of the `DataGrid` just hanging out at the end.  I've tried to style it so that the last column is just transparent, but so far no such luck.

I think the ideal solution here is to have the button be external of the `DataGrid`, but to follow the selected row.  I have no idea how to do this.  I'm probably going to have to bind the margin of the button to the `DataGrid`, but I'm not sure how to fetch the selected row or calculate the correct margin off of that.  I haven't had the google juice to find any information on this unfortunately.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edited to add:

I posted a solution.  If you have a better solution, please post it and if I agree that it is better I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked a solution.  I'm not thrilled with the layout of the code though.  I use a couple of lines that feel like bad hacks that might need to be cleaned up, but this does work.  Normally, I try to stay away from code for UI, but this is all layout stuff, so I'll give it a pass.

```
    private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        refreshButton();
    }

    private void dataGrid_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        refreshButton();
    }

    private void refreshButton()
    {

        if (dataGrid.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Int32 val;
            // This is the first bit that I don't like.  I pulled this code from
            // another website that showed how to get the selected row as a FrameworkElement
            // There is perhaps a more intuitive way to do this
            FrameworkElement element = dataGrid.Columns.Last().GetCellContent(dataGrid.SelectedItem);

            Point selectedRow = element.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            Point grd = dataGrid.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

            val = Int32.Parse(Math.Round(selectedRow.Y + element.ActualHeight/2 - grd.Y - DelButton.ActualHeight/2).ToString());

            // This is the other bit I don't like.  Magic numbers to make sure the delete
            // box doesn't hang out above or below on a scroll.  
            // I think I can get around this by getting the bounds of the elements and
            // doing the math off of that.  I'll probably swing back to it later.
            if (val > 110 || val < 10)
                DelButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            else
                DelButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            Canvas.SetTop(DelButton, val);
        }
        else
            DelButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

So the basic idea here is that I have a Canvas that is next to my DataGrid with a single button inside.  The canvas is adjustable height to align with the DataGrid as it grows.  As the selection changes or the DataGrid scrolls, we update the button's location and if it is visible or not.